# file input int strings c

Tags: c, function, file-io

So I'm having issues right now with my program. I'm trying to get it to open a file count the lines rewind and then go through the file to store the variables.
`String String String int` is the format of the file but I'm having issues after I count the lines. I can print the numbers to the screen but then I get a seg fault right after the print. I don't know why

```
int countLines(FILE * fin){
int count=0;
char street[100];
char city[100];
char state[3];
int zip;

do{
    fgets(street, 100, fin);
    fgets(city, 100, fin);
    fgets(state, 3, fin);
    fscanf(fin, "%d\n", &zip);
    count++;
}while(!feof(fin));

rewind(fin);

return count;
```

}

`lines=countLines(fin);` is how I call the function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: fgets reads entire line until the end of file or newline. Are your "String String String int" values line by line or all in one line?

Comment: it's one line for each entry.
String\n
String\n
String\n
int\n

Comment: Not checking *any* of those `fgets()` calls, nor `fscanf()`, for result codes should be put at the top of your list of "what-i'm-doing-wrong", followed shortly thereafter by using `feof()` as a break condition in a while-loop, [which is nearly always wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not mix `fgets()` with `fscanf()` until you are *very* comfortable with these functions.  They do not play well together.  That `\n` in the format is a white space and will match *any* number of consecutive white space including multiple `\n`, spaces, tabs, etc.

```
// fscanf(fin, "%d\n", &zip);
```

Recommend avoiding `feof()` and using the return value from `fgets()`.

`feof()` does not become true until a file read is attempted and fails to provide a `char`.  This is different than "true when none left".  Example: you read the last `char` of a file.  `feof()` is still false.  Code attempts to read more (and fails).  *Now* `feof()` is true.  (and remains true).

Do count the lines in a simple fashion and use symmetry.  Further consider more error checking.  Read the zip code line as a string and *then* parse it as an integer.

```
int countLines(FILE * fin){
  int count=0;
  char street[100];
  char city[100];
  char state[100];
  char zips[100];
  unsigned zip;

  while (fgets(street, sizeof street, fin) != NULL) {
    count++;
  }
  rewind(fin);

  if (count%4 != 0) Handle_LineCountNotMultipleof4();

  // You could return here, but let's read the file again and get the data.
  // This is likely part of OP's next step.
  for (int i=0; i<count; i += 4) {
    if ((NULL == fgets(street, sizeof street, fin)) ||
      (NULL == fgets(city,   sizeof city, fin)) ||
      (NULL == fgets(state,  sizeof state, fin)) ||
      (NULL == fgets(zips,   sizeof zips, fin)) ||
      (1 != sscanf(zips, "%u", &zip))) handle_error();
    // Remember street, city, state, still have an ending \n
    do_something(street, city, state, zip);
  }
  return count;
}
```

Alternatively, to count the lines use the following.  A singular difficulty occurs in reading if you have long lines, so let's check that as we go.  Take this out `line length` stuff if you prefer a simple answer.  You could use the `Maxline+1` as you buffer size instead of a fixed 100.

```
  size_t Maxline = 0;
  size_t Curline = 0;
  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) {
    Curline++;
    if (ch == '\n') {
      count++;
      if (Curline > Maxline) MaxLine = Curline;
      Curline = 0;  
    }
  }
  if ((Maxline + 1) > 100) TroubleAhead() ; // Trouble with future (fgets(buf, 100, fin), use bigger buffers
  rewind(fin);
```

Comment: when I try to get the values stored into the variables (street, city, state, zip) I get a segmentation fault after the function call of countLines. What causes that? It's after I print the number to the screen. Is it because of the trailing \n? How do you remove the trailing \n from an int?

Comment: @kevorski For debug, let  `do_something()` be `printf("s:<%s> c:<%s> S:<%s> z:<%u>\n", street, city, state, zip)`.  Double check your and my usage of `zips` (a char array) and `zip` (an integer).

Comment: I got it working. Just having issues elsewhere now haha

Comment: @kevorski Oh happy day!

Answer (score 0):

fgets tries to read a whole line,not just a word, which seems to be what you are hoping for.
So, the buffers you are passing it arent big enough, and they won't get what you were hopign for and you are incrementign the count once for every 3 lines and fscan usually wont read a line leaving the remains of that line to interfere with your next read.

If you want to read words, try scanf, with %s. If you want to read a fixed number of chars, try fread.

Comment: I know I'm doing an increment once every 4 lines. I'm using a struct to which is street city state zip. can you give example of scanf? Right now I just get a blank screen once I input the file name @RichardPlunkett